# Angular getDocumentById

Tags: angular

I have a component that is trying to add a class to an SVG element based on an id I am passing it (InputSeats) which does match the svg element ID. The code I have below **works** but concerned that I have to use document.getElementByID() to pass into Render2 and wondering what a more angular centric approach is. I may not be asking the right question but hope what I am asking makes sense. The ID is not known initially on the component load which is why initially grabbing the container

```
 export class ViewChartComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('seats', { static: true }) seats: ElementRef;
  @Input() InputSeats: SeatCoordinate[];

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.colorSeat(this.formatSeats(this.InputSeats))
  }

  colorSeat(seatNumber: string[]): void {
    seatNumber.forEach(seat => {
      this.renderer.removeClass(document.getElementById(seat), 'cls-4')
      this.renderer.removeClass(document.getElementById(seat), 'cls-7')
      this.renderer.removeClass(document.getElementById(seat), 'cls-8')
      this.renderer.setStyle(document.getElementById(seat), 'fill', '#000')
    })
  }

  formatSeats(input: SeatCoordinate[]): string[] {
    return input.map(seat => (seat.sectionCode + '.' + seat.rowNumber + '.' + seat.seatNumber))
  }

}
```

a brief sample of the HTML:

```
<g #seats id="SEAT_RECTANGLES" data-name="SEAT RECTANGLES">
<rect id="303.HH.41" class="cls-3" x="480.24" y="576.74" width="7.68" height="11.32"/>
<rect id="303.HH.42" class="cls-3" x="489.72" y="576.74" width="7.68" height="11.32"/>
<rect id="303.HH.43" class="cls-3" x="499.19" y="576.74" width="7.68" height="11.32"/>
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

your document.getElementById('seats') is `this.seats.nativeElement`

But you can also use variables and ngClass class or similar, e.g.

```
<g #seats id="SEAT_RECTANGLES" [class]="myVariable" 
   [fill]="myColor" data-name="SEAT RECTANGLES">
...
</g>
```

And

```
myVariable="class-1 class-2"
myColor="#ff00ff"
```

This is not only about the svg, you can use also with path. Some time you need use [attr."property"], e.g. in a path you can use

```
<path [attr.path]="path" [attr.fill]="fillColor">
```

and

```
path="M0,0 L20 30"
fillColor="red"
```